# Count all characters in file during reading CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, csvhelper

I just want to ask you if there is any possibilities to get the number of all characters in file during reading the CSV file? I don't want to load file into memory two times (one time for parsing, second time for counting).

I need to parse CSV file but also I need to get the number of all characters in this file (with delimeters). Someone has any idea how to do that in the most efficient way?

```
   using (TextReader stream = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
   {
        CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(stream, GetCsvReaderOptions());
        while (reader.Read())
        {
             //parsing
        }
   }
```

- There is an option to iterate through all fields in actual reader row
  and at the end increment length by delimeters (number of fields ==
  number of delimeters).
- Also I have idea to count characters on parsed objects by reflection
  (get all properties value from object).

I don't think that these options will be efficient.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please define: "character". What do you, personally, think it means? And what do you think the .NET CLR defines it as as compared to the Unicode consortium? Note that a UTF-16 `Char` is not the same thing as a single discrete glyph. What about ligatures? Or in the case of denormalized Unicode?

Comment: @Dai I think I mean any character in file (digits, letters, special chars, whitespaces)

Comment: @Mateusz Which is exactly what Dai also means. You need to think about the points raised before counting "characters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Reader.Context.RawRecord` and remove the line endings. (Assuming you don't want to count those)

```cs
using (TextReader stream = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
{
    var count = 0;

    CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(stream, GetCsvReaderOptions());
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        count += reader.Context.RawRecord.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Length;
        //parsing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic way of doing this could be the following:

```
using (TextReader stream = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
{
     var content = stream.ReadToEnd();
     var length = content.Length;
}
```

So that variable "length" will contain the count of all symbols in the passed file

Comment: I will need to open stream second time of the same file because if I will ReadToEnd() with CsvReader in the same using block, after fire ReadToEnd(), EndOfStream will be set to true. Also I don't think that it will be most efficient. Thanks for your response